# Java adding data to table using SQL

Tags: java, sql, insert, addition

I am using an sql query to add data data to an existing database table.
I want to add data under the columns 'Room_Resource' and 'Quantity'.
The system is designed to allow bookings and i am trying to add bookings made to a tblBookings table, the code below is taken from JButton clicked function.

- The value I want to add to Room_Resource is a name taken from a selected table within the system. I declared a variable for this 'resourceChosenString'
- The value I want to add to quantity is from the 'Quantity' variable i have declared in relation to a combo box.

Here are my declarations:

```
int selectedResourceRow = tblResources.getSelectedRow();       
Object resourceChosen = tblResources.getValueAt(selectedResourceRow,1);   
String resourceChosenString = resourceChosen.toString();   
int Quantity = cmbQuantity.getSelectedIndex();
```

I then have a sql statement:

```
String sql = ("INSERT INTO tblBookings (Room_Resource,Quantity) VALUES (" + resourceChosenString + " ', ' " + Quantity + " ',)  ");
```

And then the execute code:

```
try{  
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
pst.execute();   
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added");  
} catch (Exception e){  
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error Adding Booking");  
}
```

Currently it gives me an error when I attempt to add the data to the table and wondered if anyone had any suggestions?

Also I considered that perhaps the problem could lie in the fact I have more than two columns in the external table and the table I am adding the data to so columns could be left blank. If this could be the problem, could anyone tell me how to get around it? Possibly if there is a null function I can use instead of values.

Comment: What is the error you get, update your post with the stacktrace too

Answer (score 0):

The SQL you are generating is not valid and looks like this;

```
INSERT INTO tblBookings (Room_Resource,Quantity) VALUES (resource ', ' 1 ',)  
                                                         ^                ^
                                             missing quote       extraneous comma
```

You should tidy it up, or better still use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

```
String sql = "insert into tblBookings (Room_Resource,Quantity) values (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
pst.setString(1, resourceChosenString);
pst.setInt(2, quantity);  //variable names are not capitalised by convention
pst.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to tell us what database you're using and what error message you're getting.  But just off the bat, it looks like your sql string is not formatted correctly.  I don't know if you mistyped it in the question or if your code has a simple syntax error.

Just shooting from the hip with what you have, it looks like your sql statement should be:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblBookings (Room_Resource,Quantity) VALUES ('" + resourceChosenString + "', " + Quantity + ")";
```

Notice that `resourceChosenString` should be wrapped in single quotes (you're missing the single quote on the left).  Also, I don't think you're supposed to wrap a number in single quotes (I could be wrong since I don't know which database you're using).

Qwerky is right though; you should use a `PreparedStatement`.